# Review Request - Android CountDownTimer activity

Tags: java, android, beginner

I'm new to Java and Android.  While I've created a project that seems to work, I'd like some opinions on how to make it better.

The app is going to be used as an interval workout timer/music player for Android devices. I know there's a ton of these already, but I thought it'd be a good way to learn the language, and it's useful for me. I haven't gotten the music player piece working yet. I was thinking of letting you select between selecting a playlist to play or using the 8tracks.com API to play streaming music. Comments are welcome, too.

The code can be seen in full [in this Github](https://github.com/iyeager2004/WorkoutStopwatch).

Here's the main package:

```
package com.blueflamesys.workoutstopwatch;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.CountDownTimer;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class WorkoutStopwatch extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

private static final String TAG = "WorkoutMain";
private static final String API_KEY = "30eee341eb88a9647b40d187faf508b50ca318d9";
private boolean timerRunning, isPaused = false;
private long millisLeft = 0;
private WorkoutTimer workoutTimer;
private enum CounterState {
    UNKNOWN(0),
    WORKOUT(1), 
    REST(2);

    private int stateValue;

    CounterState(int state) {
        this.stateValue = state;
    }

    public int getStateValue() {
        return stateValue;
    }

    public void setStateValue(int state) {
        this.stateValue = state;
    }       
}
CounterState state = CounterState.WORKOUT;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.workout_stopwatch); 

    // Set up OnClickListeners
    ((Button) findViewById(R.id.start_button)).setOnClickListener(this);
    ((Button) findViewById(R.id.pause_button)).setOnClickListener(this);
    ((Button) findViewById(R.id.reset_button)).setOnClickListener(this);

}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch(v.getId()) {
    case R.id.start_button:
        Log.d(TAG, "clicked on Start Button");
        if (!isPaused && !timerRunning) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Wasn't paused and wasn't running...");

            timerRunning = true;

            // If the state is unknown, set it to Workout first
            int State = state.getStateValue();
            if (State == 0) {
                state.setStateValue(1);
            }
            workoutTimer = new WorkoutTimer(50);
            workoutTimer.start();

        } 

        if (isPaused) {
            timerRunning = true;
            this.resumeTimer();
            Log.d(TAG, "Was paused resumed timer...");
        }

        break;
    case R.id.pause_button:
        Log.d(TAG, "clicked on Pause Button");

        if (timerRunning) {
            timerRunning = false;
            this.pauseTimer();
            Log.d(TAG, "Paused timer...");
        }

        break;
    case R.id.reset_button:

        Log.d(TAG, "clicked on Reset Button");

        if (!timerRunning) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Wasn't running...");
            isPaused = false;
            TextView digital_display = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.digital_display);
            digital_display.setText("00:00.0");
        }
        break;
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.stopwatch_settings, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.settings:
        startActivity(new Intent(this, Prefs.class));
        return true;
    case R.id.about:
        Intent i = new Intent(this, About.class);
        startActivity(i);
        break;
    }
return false;
}

public void pauseTimer() {
    isPaused = true;
    SharedPreferences workoutTimerDB = getSharedPreferences("workoutTimerDB", MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor edit = workoutTimerDB.edit();
    edit.putLong("millisLeft", (Long)this.millisLeft);
    edit.commit();
    workoutTimer.cancel();
}

public void resumeTimer() {
    if (isPaused) {
        isPaused = false;
        SharedPreferences workoutTimerDB = getSharedPreferences("workoutTimerDB", MODE_PRIVATE);
        millisLeft = workoutTimerDB.getLong("millisLeft", 0);
        workoutTimer = new WorkoutTimer(millisLeft, 50);
        workoutTimer.start();
    }
}

private class WorkoutTimer extends CountDownTimer{
    public WorkoutTimer(long interval) {
        super(getThisTime(), interval);
        Log.d(TAG, "WorkoutTimer Constructed with interval only...");
    }

    public WorkoutTimer(long millis, long interval) {
        super(millis, interval);
        Log.d(TAG, "WorkoutTimer Constructed with both...");
    }

    public void onFinish() {
        int State = state.getStateValue();
        int roundsLeft = 0;

        if (State == 1) {
            state.setStateValue(2);
        } else {
            state.setStateValue(1);
            decrementRounds();
        }

        Log.d(TAG, "WorkoutState = " + state.getStateValue());

        try {
            TextView numOfRounds = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.number_of_rounds);

            roundsLeft = Integer.parseInt(numOfRounds.getText().toString());
        } catch(NumberFormatException nfe) {
            roundsLeft = 999;
        }

        if (roundsLeft > 0) { // If there's still rounds, start the timer.
            workoutTimer = new WorkoutTimer(100);
            workoutTimer.start();
        } else { // Stop the timer and reset the display
            workoutTimer.cancel();

            TextView digital_display = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.digital_display);
            digital_display.setText("00:00.0");
        }
    }

    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
        final long minutes_left = ((millisUntilFinished / 1000) / 60);
        final long seconds_left = (millisUntilFinished / 1000) - (minutes_left * 60);
        final long millis = millisUntilFinished % 100;
        final String time_left = String.format("%02d:%02d.%01d", minutes_left, seconds_left, 
                millis/10);

        TextView digital_display = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.digital_display);
        digital_display.setText(time_left);
        millisLeft = millisUntilFinished;
    }

    @Override
    protected void finalize() throws Throwable {
        super.finalize();
        Log.d(TAG, "Object destroyed");
    }
}

private long getThisTime() {
    long time = 0;

    TextView workout_time = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.workout_time);
    TextView rest_time = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.rest_time);

    switch(state.getStateValue()) {
    case 1:
        try {
                time = Integer.parseInt(workout_time.getText().toString());
            } catch(NumberFormatException nfe) {
                time = 999;
            } 
        Log.d(TAG, "Workout time = " + time);
        break;
    case 2:
        try {
                time = Integer.parseInt(rest_time.getText().toString());
            } catch(NumberFormatException nfe) {
                time = 999;
            } 
        Log.d(TAG, "Rest time = " + time);
        break;
    case 0:
        time = 0;
        break;
    }
    return time * 1000;
}

private void decrementRounds() {
    int roundsLeft = 2;

    TextView numOfRounds = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.number_of_rounds);

    try {
        roundsLeft = Integer.parseInt(numOfRounds.getText().toString());
    } catch(NumberFormatException nfe) {
        roundsLeft = 999;
    }

    roundsLeft -= 1;

    numOfRounds.setText(String.valueOf(roundsLeft));
    Log.d(TAG, "set rounds to = " + roundsLeft);
}

}
```

Don't hold back, and feel free to ask any questions or give any criticisms.

Answer (score 2):

**Your usage of enums**

You are misusing your enums. I would get rid of the `getStateValue` and `setStateValue` methods. **The enum itself is a state.**

I would change code that looks like this:

```
        int State = state.getStateValue();
        if (State == 0) {
            state.setStateValue(1);
        }
```

To this:

```
        if (state == UNKNOWN) {
            state.setStateValue(WORKOUT);
        }
```

What your original code here actually does is that it's taking the `state` value, which you initialize to `CounterState.WORKOUT` and then it's changing the **internal integer value** stored in the enum. You never change your `state` variable from `WORKOUT`, but instead you change the integer value of the `WORKOUT`-state. That's definitely not how enums should be used.

(You're also using the variable name `State` which defies Java coding conventions that variable names should start with a lower case letter)

So, by changing the code snippet in the way I suggested above you will get rid of a lot of the "magic numbers" 0, 1 and 2 by using your enums properly. You will also improve readability. You won't have to remember "Which state is 2" anymore.

I would also mark the enum type itself with `static` like this: `private static enum CounterState {` because the `CounterState` is not dependent on anything in your outer class). I would also mark its constructor with `private` - or rather, I would **get rid of the constructor entirely.** There is no use for it when you remove the `getStateValue` and `setStateValue` methods. You can use `state.ordinal()` if you really want to access its int value (which you should generally try to avoid but is useful for things like serialization). The `ordinal()` method returns the index of the enum.

**Other variables**

I would rename your `isPaused` to simply `paused`. `isPaused` is a naming convention for a method that returns your internal `paused` boolean value. You also have one boolean for if the timer is running (`timerRunning`) and one for if the timer is paused. This confuses me a lot. If the timer isn't running, then it's paused isn't it? Or should the possible options be `STOPPED`, `PAUSED`, `RUNNING`? In that case make it an `enum` (without any getters and setters!).

**On click**

I also agree with @thepoosh about defining `onClick` for your buttons in the XML, unless you're targeting Android API < 4 (which no-one really uses anymore). For information about using `onClick` in your XML, [see the Android documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Button.html).

Answer (score 1):

from the little I saw I have just a few comments (the code looks fairly fine)

1. if all you do with the buttons is set the `onClickListener` there is no reason not to use the built in xml attribute `onClick` when designing the buttons.
2. when editing or reading from `SharedPrefrences` you should probably synchronize it like this:

   ```
   public static final String WORKOUT_SHARED_PREFS = "workoutTimerDB";
   public void pauseTimer() {
   isPaused = true;
   synchronized(WORKOUT_SHARED_PREFS) {
           SharedPreferences workoutTimerDB = getSharedPreferences(WORKOUT_SHARED_PREFS, MODE_PRIVATE);
           SharedPreferences.Editor edit = workoutTimerDB.edit();
           edit.putLong("millisLeft", (Long)this.millisLeft);
           edit.commit();
           WORKOUT_SHARED_PREFS.notifyAll();
       }
       workoutTimer.cancel();
   }
   ```

Comment: I agree about defining `onClick` within the XML, but I don't see any need to synchronize editing or reading from `SharedPreferences`. AFAIK, Android is capable of doing that itself.